# Android use physical button in background

Tags: java, android, button, broadcastreceiver

I want to call BroadcastReceiver when sound button and power button is presed.

I have try with a reciver with SCREEN_ON action, is not working.
Or if is posibly call receiver when screnshot taken.

Thanks !

Comment: Not sure this is possible due to being very bad for security.

Comment: for button or screnshot event ?